# Does this kind of circuit work?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries, electrochemistry

I am going to see if having electric voltage through fruit will slow the decay.

So I have my treatment set up here:

[image]

and I am going to wrap this so that:

[image]

However, my teacher told me that this might not work because in order for the circuit to work, I need to have two types of metals. Also he told me that I need some sort of way to "ground" this. I do not understand why this wouldn't work.

Also, how should I change this so that the fruit will have electric voltage going through, or at least have a contact with electric voltage?

Comment: Your real problem is that you're going to have all the electricity passing through the foil, not the banana. If you want a voltage across the banana, you'll have to attach the leads across the banana, no foil.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to damage the banana? @JahanClaes

Comment: Right @JahanClaes . And you'll probably want to measure the current that's flowing. How much current do you need to keep bacteria from multiplying? How much current can the banana tolerate without cooking. How much voltage do you need to get to just the right current? Cool science fair project!

Comment: Also to answer your other question. Two *different* metals are not required to *drive* current. You do however need dissimilar metals if you were to have the banana act as a battery electrolyte.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap the whole thing in aluminum foil (that is the intention, right?), then the current will *only* travel through that aluminum. Simply because it is much more conducting than the banana, and the contact to the banana is not so good.

A sidenote: You **should not** do this, because that would be a short circuit. It is the same as attaching a wired directly form end to end of a battery. A very high current will flow in a short circuit, where it isn't braked, and this will produce extreme heat. And melt / burn something. But well, if you work with a battery and a large foil sheet, the effect will be limited...

If you wish to actually have current running through the banana, then stick the electrodes through the surface into the creamy banana bulk at each end. Be sure they have good contact, so don't wiggle too much. Avoid air bubbles etc.

I can't say anything about how or if this will work, since I have no clue about the conductivity or ease of such experiment on a banana, but if the banana has some conductivity and can let electrons move around (just like they can do through your own body of you touch an electric fence), this might give a result.

About the grounding, this really depends on the equipment - specifically  on the voltage source. If it is a battery, I don't see any need with such low voltage, but let someone more experienced with electronics answer that.

Comment: A dangerous short circuit, with a AA battery?

Comment: That's a good point @EmilioPisanty . I'll keep that remark in there until we know for sure what the voltage source actually is.

Comment: That said, I do have a burning question: is there a place where I can buy a mug like the one in your profile picture?

Comment: I don't know about a AA, but I've melted copper wires by shorting them to a C battery.

Comment: Another problem that this answer points out: neither of your teacher's recommendations are valid.  You don't need two types of metals and you don't need a "ground."  Thus, you should be aware that either a) you did not properly describe the setup to your teacher or b) your teacher doesn't really understand electricity.  In either case, you should be aware that you're basically experimenting on your own, without "supervision."  Make sure you are comfortable with taking sole responsibility for any side effects that may occur.  Just use good judgement.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, I know a place where you can buy a mug and a pen.